# Offer vs offer oneself

Tags: phrase-choice

Are both options correct or just one of them? Why?

My classmates and I can **offer / offer ourselves** for acting.

The situation is: a teacher is looking for some students willing to act in a play.

Comment: *My classmates and I **volunteer** [for acting / to act]*.

Answer (score 1):

"We can offer for acting" is definitely wrong. "Offer to act" would be grammatically correct. "for acting" here is a adjectival phrase so needs a noun, therefore "we can offer ourselves for acting" is correct.

The best depends on the purpose of the sentance. If this is a statement about your intentions to a third party then that is fine. If it's an answer to the teacher something like "we can act for you" would be better.